# UITableView or UITableViewCell ? Prompts "Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I can't understand why my `UITableView` can't display properly in sometimes. It prompts `"Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"`.

PS: `condTempTableViewCell` is custom `UITableViewCell` with `IBOutlet` controls.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([indexPath section] == 1)
        return self.condTempTableViewCell;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [condStatusArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];        

    return cell;
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Enable nszombie first and find out what is problem

```
Double-click an executable in the Executables group of your Xcode project.
Click the Arguments tab.
In the "Variables to be set in the environment:" section, make a variable called "NSZombieEnabled" and set its value to "YES".
```

and for custom cell

```
 if ([indexPath section] == 1) {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
  CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id oneObject in nib) {
            if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]]) {
                cell = (CustomCell *)oneObject;
                break;
            }
        }
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
}
return cell;
```

custom cell returned somthing like this

good luck

Comment: but my UITableViewCell is same location with my UITableView xib, this also work for my situation?

Comment: you have created your uitableviewCustomcell rite? then it will not be any problem your can call by above method.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger will also show you exactly which line failed (well, usually, if the error occurs in your code). I'm going to guess you are overreleasing condStatusArray (how is it created?).

The debugger's instruction pointer would be at this line then:
    [condStatusArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

Comment: if ([indexPath section] == 1)
        return self.condTempTableViewCell;

i think is this line problem, if i cancel it, it won't prompt error. FYI, it prompt error in sometimes only...

Comment: Do you have the property / setter for condTempTableViewCell set up correctly? Are you retaining it correctly?

Comment: Read up on outlet memory management here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmNibObjects.html

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *condTempTableViewCell;
somethings like tat?

Comment: do u hav any example to connect a custom tableviewcell that in a tableview xib?

Comment: Yes, the @property should be like that. Take a look here for custom cell loading (there are many ways to do that, Google away). Look at the section "Loading Custom Table-View Cells From Nib Files". http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

Answer (score 0):

This code would probably crash if you have more than one row in section 1.  Show us your implementations of `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.

Also, in your NIB click on the cell connected to condTempTableViewCell and check its Identifier in the attributes inspector.  Make sure the identifier is something other than @"Cell".

Comment: It shows reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Here is my sec n row methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return section == 0 ? [self.condStatusArray count] : 1;
}

Comment: Straight return condTempTableViewCell;

is it the correct way to show the custom cell?

Comment: It sounds like `self.condTempTableViewCell` is nil when you return it.  You probably forgot to connect that outlet to the custom cell object in your NIB.